# How to protect from WPAD attacks?

Tags: windows, proxy, dns, spoofing, windows-server

If you are in a Windows network, and you basically connect to a website ; And there is an attacker on Linux who changes the `hostname` to `WPAD` and configures WPAD.dat in his system, all your PC's traffic can be captured (or) spoofed.

WPAD.dat - Something like:

```
function FindProxyForUrl(url, h){

    return "FAKE PROXY";

}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a client device, simply turn off the "Automatically detect proxy settings" feature in Internet Options. This prevents the browser from trying to look up a location for the `wpad.dat` or proxy PAC script.

If you want to protect poorly configured devices on your network, set a DNS entry for `WPAD` and blackhole the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS entry to 127.0.0.1 is only helpful if the computer is inside a corporate network. In a home environment or at a public wireless site you have to rely on the browsers "Automatically detect proxy settings." If the browser has been re-installed or a new one installed the settings Proxy settings may still be turned on. To protect the system, put an entry for WPAD in the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

EG:     127.0.0.1   WPAD